# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Tags: ios8, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension, bundle-identifier

“I am going to upload the binary of my app which contains App Extension but it give errors that the

> bundle Identifier of the containing app does not matching with theExtension App.
>    CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'AppExtension' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'
>    Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Profile Name”)has an AppID of “com.CompanyName.AppName” which does not match your bundle identifier “com.CompanyName.AppName.ExtensionName”

If we use the same Bundle Identifier then it gives error during the binary uploading.

```
     “The app extension is not signed with the valid Provisioning certificate”
    Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. 
Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I guess you miss bundle ID

Comment: Have you tried with Code Signing Verification?

Comment: hi guys I'm also facing the same problem , can any body help me out on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved it by creating separate bundle ID and distribution profile for each Container app and App extension.you should assign main container app ID to create app on store.

Comment: Can you please provide me brief description? because I have working on Share  extension so I need to create Two AppID and provisional profile (development & distribution?) and also enable appGroup in both with same group ID ?

Comment: How you created , could you add some detail description ?

Answer (score 9):

Each extension is a separate target just like the host app. If you have 3 extensions for example, you will need 4 bundle IDs each including the host app, and 4 provisioning profile each.

Each target has its own set of configuration, so if host app and extensions all support CloudKit, you need to turn CloudKit on for each app ID.

Just treat them as separate apps.

Comment: Can you please provide me brief description? because I have working on Share extension so I need to create Two AppID and provisional profile (development & distribution?) and also enable appGroup in both with same group ID ?